# putting line-height in select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, styles

how is putting `line-height: 40px;` for `option` in `select box`?

```
<select class="select_box">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" style="display: none;">Categories</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>25</option>
    <option>50</option>
    <option>100</option>
    <option>all</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to alter a select list in this way. You can add padding but it is not reliable in various browsers. To alter the look and feel of a select list reliably you will need to use javascript.

Here is one method :
http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
.select_box{font-size:12px;padding:14px;}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/dk9p2/

Or you can change the font-size:

```
.select_box{font-size:30px;}
```

More options [here](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/select-single/).

**Note** It all depends on the browser. The previous doesn't work in < ie8

**UPDATE :** Little more can be achieved through css alone : http://jsfiddle.net/dk9p2/1/

Comment: i want for option no select. i use of chrome

Comment: Do you just want to hide the first option? or disable the entire `<select>` tag?

Comment: no, i want create distance between <option> tags with padding or line-height.

Comment: I've updated my answer, you can't style individual `<option>` tags

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   option {font-size: 40px;}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <select>
   <option>Internet Explorer 11</option>
   <option>Mozilla Firefox 38.0.5</option>
   <option>Opera 30.0.1835.125</option>
   <option>Google Chrome 43.0.2357.81 dev-m</option>
  </select>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can not add a font size to options in a select.  The styling of the select options is handled by the browser