# Which CSS Styles are allowed on Dropdown Menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, accessibility

I'm trying to apply these 3 CSS properties on dropdown menu:
https://jsfiddle.net/zLx4gbdn/12/
`line-height: 1.5 !important; letter-spacing: 0.12em !important; word-spacing: 0.16em !important;`

If you see, only is applied on selected option, not in the others.

I see this thread [putting line-height in select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939755/putting-line-height-in-select-box) and it seems this cannot be possible to do.
Is this true? If this is the case, do you know where I can find more info about this?

I try to apply js but, like the fiddle, it only applies the color property but not the others. [js console test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQcpf.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "allowed"?